# Does PHP's garbage collection mechanism handle recursive reference issue?

Tags: php, perl, garbage-collection

In perl this will cause recursive reference :

```
$a = \$a;
```

And `$a`'s reference count will never come to `0` again...

Does PHP has similar issue?

If not,how does PHP gc handles it?

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP's Garbage collector *can* and *will* collect graphs of objects that contain cycles.

See [PHP: Collecting Cycles](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php)

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3's got a new garbage collector that can break such circular references. In previous versions, the self-reference would cause a memory leak and eventually kill the script. 5.3 can break the reference and clean up properly.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

Comment: @Marc B,a brief introduction how PHP handles it?

Comment: @Je Rog: The brief introduction is linked, the algorithm is linked therein: http://www.research.ibm.com/people/d/dfb/papers/Bacon01Concurrent.pdf

Comment: @hakre,does it have performance issue?AFAIK,Perl doesn't fix this issue just for performance issue.

Comment: garbage collection is expensive, no matter how you do it. So yes, there is a performance issue.

Comment: @Je Rog: I dunno, I'm not firm with perls internals for variables. Normally in PHP when unsetting the self reference, it will unset the referenced value as well. The GC in PHP is optional, so you can disable it in case it's too expensive.

Comment: Mark B is correct; gc is always expensive.  Perl5 does only reference count based gc, which means no surge of expense when gc kicks, instead spreading the expense more evenly over just about all operations.

Comment: @Marc B: In your answer you write "*such circular references*". To what kind of circular references are you referring to? `$a = &$a`?

Comment: @hakre: yes. Anything that eventually points back itself, through whoever many levels, is circular. `$a = &$a` is just the simplest.

Comment: `$a = &$a` does not need any garbage collection in PHP. So for *such* a circular reference it's not expensive at all. Just saying, I think it's worth to differ to the cases where garbage collection actually applies to.

Comment: Yes, it does. Your example below is invalid, by continuously redoing `$a = &$a` you're breaking the circular reference yourself and making a new one each iteration. Instead, try doing something like `$arr[$i] = &$arr[$i]` in a loop and build up a large set of CircRefs you'll see the memory leak. Let that array go out of scope, and if you're on 5.2 or older, it'd be a memory leak. Remember - once a variable's marked as a reference, it STAYS a reference even if you later assign it something completely different.

Comment: @Marc B: Well, the OP asked about the `$a = &$a` case specifically, I won't consider that example invalid then ;). And I don't understand why you assume it's valuable to remember that a reference is a reference (and therefore "stays" as you coined it).

Comment: @Marc B: You mean `$arr[$i] = &$arr[$i]` in a loop [like so](http://ideone.com/qTr4g)? Can't see a memory leak in PHP 5.2.11 after going out of scope. Remember that there is a code example as part of my answer that actually shows where garbage collection in PHP applies (or is necessary for, even 5.3).

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not Perl. There is no way to create actual memory references as it's more known from C pointers. *"References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual memory addresses, [...]"* ([*What References Are*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php)).

Such an recursive reference on to the same memory address is actually not possible to reproduce with PHP references and zval containers. Therefore PHP GC does not have to deal with anything like shown in the perl excerpt.

(If you're able to actually create such a recursive memory reference with PHP which I doubt is possible, please add the PHP example code to your question.)

### Recursive References in PHP

How does a recursive reference in PHP looks like? In fact, there is no recursion. In PHP "*variable name and variable content are different*" ([*What References Are*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php)), so there never is true recursion in sense of a memory address' value referencing that memory address.

The highest you can get is a variable that is both: aliasing a value (standard variable) and being additionally an alias to the same value again:

```
$a = 'value';
$a = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
```

Output:

```
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=1)='value'
```

It has a value and references that value of itself.

### "Garbage Collection" of `$a = &$a` then

So for that PHP example, how does garbage collection come into play? The answer is not at all. There is actually no "cyclic" reference to resolve in this `$a = &$a` case. It's just a simple container with a reference count of one while being a reference. PHP garbage collection on or off (or better running cycle collection or not) it does not make any difference. Considering the following test-script for the `$a = &$a` case:

```
function alocal($collectCycles) {
    $a = str_repeat('a', 1048576);

    $collectCycles && gc_collect_cycles();
    var_dump(xdebug_memory_usage());

    $a = &$a;

    $collectCycles && gc_collect_cycles();
    var_dump(xdebug_memory_usage());

    xdebug_debug_zval('a');
}

$collectCycles = false; // or true

$collectCycles ? gc_enable() : gc_disable();

$collectCycles && gc_collect_cycles();
var_dump(xdebug_memory_usage());

alocal($collectCycles);

$collectCycles && gc_collect_cycles();
var_dump(xdebug_memory_usage());
```

Running it with `$collectCycles = false;` or `$collectCycles = true;` does not make the slightest difference:

#### Running without collecting cycles:

```
int(660680)
int(1709328)
int(1709328)
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=1)='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...'
int(660848)
```

#### Running with collecting cycles:

```
int(660680)
int(1709328)
int(1709328)
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=1)='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...'
int(660848)
```

So for performance reasons and the given example, it looks like that there is not much garbage collection involved in PHP which makes sense as there is no true cyclic reference. It's just a value and a reference. Un-setting the alias is un-setting both, the value and the reference. No need for a GC to deal with cyclic references at all.

### For what is Garbage Collection in PHP useful?

The following is a demonstration code example that provokes the situation where PHP will have values in memory that are not accessible by a variable (label) any longer. These values are actually useless then because they exist only on the interpreter level and can not be accessed by PHP code any longer. Garbage collection in PHP deals with these values more or less only.

The following script will create 10 instances of a simple class that only contains a reference to itself (set in the class' constructor) and that contains a string of about one megabyte size.

Each of the instances is set to the same variable (`$instance`). Next to that label, the object self-references itself. Therefore correctly spoken the first variable the value (the concrete instance) is labeled as is `$this->self` (the private member) and the second variable is `$instance`. As `$instance` functions as a label to a new value (the next instance), only the label inside the current instance is left. Therefore the object still exists. However, it's not accessible any longer.

Using garbage collection now can free the memory used for values that are not addressable via labels any longer. This is done with `gc_collect_cycles()`.

The code:

```
define('CONSUME_PER_INSTANCE', 1048576); // in bytes

class StoreMore
{
    static $counter;
    private $self;
    private $store;
    private $number;
    public function __construct() {
        // assign object instance to a private member of itself (self-reference):
        $this->self = $this;
        $this->store = str_repeat('a', CONSUME_PER_INSTANCE); // consume some memory
        $this->number = ++ self::$counter;
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        echo 'Instance #', $this->number, ' destructed.', "\n";
    }
}

$baseMem = xdebug_memory_usage();

echo 'Memory use on start: ', number_format($baseMem, 0, '', ' '), "\n";

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    $instance = new StoreMore();
}

$diffMem = xdebug_memory_usage() - $baseMem;

echo 'Memory afterall: ', number_format(xdebug_memory_usage(), 0, '', ' '), ' - Diff: ', number_format($diffMem, 0, '', ' '), "\n";
echo 'Rough number of "instances" in afterall Diff: ', (int)($diffMem / CONSUME_PER_INSTANCE), "\n";


echo 'Garbage collecting starting...', "\n";
$result = gc_collect_cycles();
echo 'Garbage collecting ended: ', $result, "\n";

echo 'Memory after gc: ', number_format(xdebug_memory_usage(), 0, '', ' '), ' - Diff: ', number_format(xdebug_memory_usage() - $baseMem, 0, '', ' '), "\n";

unset($instance); // remove last instance

$lastDiffMem = xdebug_memory_usage() - $baseMem;

echo 'Memory after removal of last instance: ', number_format(xdebug_memory_usage(), 0, '', ' '), ' - Diff: ', number_format($lastDiffMem, 0, '', ' '), "\n";
echo 'Rough number of "instances" in last instance Diff: ', (int)($lastDiffMem / CONSUME_PER_INSTANCE), "\n";

echo 'Garbage collecting starting...', "\n";
$result = gc_collect_cycles();
echo 'Garbage collecting ended: ', $result, "\n";


echo 'Memory after final gc: ', number_format(xdebug_memory_usage(), 0, '', ' '), ' - Diff: ', number_format(xdebug_memory_usage() - $baseMem, 0, '', ' '), "\n";
```

The output:

```
Memory use on start: 695 600
Memory afterall: 11 188 800 - Diff: 10 493 056
Rough number of "instances" in afterall Diff: 10
Garbage collecting starting...
Instance #1 destructed.
Instance #2 destructed.
Instance #3 destructed.
Instance #4 destructed.
Instance #5 destructed.
Instance #6 destructed.
Instance #7 destructed.
Instance #8 destructed.
Instance #9 destructed.
Garbage collecting ended: 27
Memory after gc: 1 745 496 - Diff: 1 049 896
Memory after removal of last instance: 1 745 552 - Diff: 1 049 800
Rough number of "instances" in last instance Diff: 1
Garbage collecting starting...
Instance #10 destructed.
Garbage collecting ended: 2
Memory after final gc: 696 328 - Diff: 728
```

This example shows as well, that the actual instance still "lives", so code inside the object can still access private members (as the destructor shows). The instances will be destroyed only if the garbage collector comes into play.

Comment: @Cicada: Where is the recursive reference on the **same zval container** (as per the perl example)? I see two containers in your example: `$a` and `$a[0]`. That is not one container. Can you please update your example with only `$a` as the OP has it in the question?

Comment: You're absolutely right, my previous example is wrong. Consider this one: `class Foo {}; $foo = new Foo; $foo->self = $foo;`. (Edit: I didn't downvote btw.)

Comment: @hakre: `$a = &$a` creates a circular reference in PHP. Your entire answer is false. The garbage collector in 5.3 was SPECIFICALLY designed to break these references.

Comment: @Cicada: You still have two zval constainers, not one: `$foo` and `$foo->self`. I'll try as well, maybe we can break something ;)

Comment: @Marc B: Tried that and it works. Right. However with the garbage collector off or on, how to metric the difference?

Comment: The GC is zero cost until it kicks in. Regardless of its on/off status, PHP still does the accounting that would let the GC work. For short lived scripts that do a few things and then quit, the GC never kicks in. But for large scripts that are doing many memory-based operations (e.g. database retrievals, building large documents, etc...) the GC may kick in multiple times to clean up stale data. You just can't say for sure what the cost would be, because it's workload dependent.

Comment: Next to GC, I think a reference in Perl is somewhat different, not a Perl pro however from scanning the docs it looks like that it is actually referencing a memory address. I don't think PHP does it this way. So the meaning of GC might be somewhat different in PHP and Perl.

Comment: Re-thought my answer. Things are shifting a bit, IMHO difference between Perl and PHP regarding references are that fundamental different that the GC analogy does not apply at all. Understandable Perl is not looking for circular memory references, whereas PHP *never has* circular memory references therefore the GC still does not need to deal with.

Comment: @hakre ,what's that article for if there's no need to deal with? http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

Comment: @Je Rog: For the case `$a = &$a` it does not apply. For most uses of references it does not apply either. As far as I understand it, it's for cases whenever a variable (label) is overwritten and one or more of it's subvalues (array, class members) are not available as a label to a value any longer. But that does only apply if those members were value of their own (and not references).

Comment: @Je Rog: I've added some example code that shows garbage collection in action.

Comment: @Hakre: stop saying PHP doesn't have circular references. It does, the GC handles them as of 5.3, earlier versions didn't. Case closed. Any language/system that allows references/pointers can have circular references. The language interpreter/runtime may have checks to forbid them, but once you allow pointers/references, a circular reference becomes possible.

Comment: @Marc B: I beg your pardon, I wrote that for the example of *such* a circular reference `$a = &$a` PHP does not need any garbage collection. That's different to say, that `$a = &$a` would not be a circular reference. Infact I would say it's a reference (not a circular reference), but that's just more strictly wording and probably a more technical understanding. The point is: I never neglected that there are circular references in PHP and you find an example of such in my answer. And: only because you use a reference to the same value in PHP, it does not mean that gc comes into action.

Comment: `$a = &$a` maps to `*a = \$a` in Perl (or `*a = *a`, if you don't care about arrays, hashes and subroutines). not `$a = \$a`.